# Facebook Graph API data & ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I am using

> https://github.com/nickpinheiro/FacebookLoginASPnetWebForms/blob/master/

to get some facebook data out and I have the basic setup running. I wanted to get more data about the user (location, education, likes, etc) so I went to FB developers section, found the fields and tried getting that info.

The call doesn't return anything other than name, locale, gender, id, link. When I add location it doesn't return that info. I tried Graph API explorer and it does come back with location info. I tried using curl (URL was from Graph API debugger) and was able to get that info returned. I tried the same from ASP.NET and it doesn't return the same info. Curl does the same thing (doesn't return more than basic name, locale,etc.). I compared the URLs and other than the token everything is the same so not sure why information isn't being returned.

Comment: _“and other than the token everything is the same”_ – so most likely the tokens do not contain the same permissions; debug them to find out more.

Comment: How would I debug if the tokens have same permissions or not?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Answer (score -1):

It is probably using an older version of the Facebook API. Since version 2.x it only gives you basic info for the user. When you want more (like email, birthdate) you have to exchange the access token for an extended access token and do another request to the API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

I recently had the same problem. Almost all the libraries out there were using the old API so I ended up creating my own. But you can check out https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk or install it with NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/

Comment: Extended access token refers to the time a token is valid, before it expires. This has nothing to do with what permissions have been granted to the app; if the user has given permission to read a specific piece of their info, then you can do that with a short-lived or an extended token, makes absolutely no difference.